# how to remove data action using ajax in jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I want to delete a comment using ajax with CI when I click the button ajax successfully deleted from the database but when it successful the jquery remove function not working properly and I get this error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'remove' of undefined
```

but when I check my database its successfully deleted from database 
here is my html code.

```
<?php 
                                            if($this->session->userdata('u_id'))://session check s here
                                        ?> 
                                        <li role="presentation">
                                            <a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="javascript:void(0)" class="delete_comment" data-id="<?php echo $row->video_comment_id ?>" data-action="<?php echo site_url('videosd/deletecomment') ?>">
                                                Delete
                                            </a>
                                        </li>
                                       <?php endif
```

And here is my jQuery code:

```
$('.delete_comment').click(function(){
        var comment_id = $(this).data('id'); 
        //alert(comment_id);
                $.ajax({
                    url: $(this).data('action'),
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: {
                        comment_id:comment_id
                    },
                    success:function(data)
                    {
                        if (data == 'yes') 
                            {
                                $(this).data('id').remove();
                            } 
                            else
                            {
                                alert('somthing wrong please tell the admin')
                            };
                    },
                    error:function()
                    {
                        $('#user_serach').text('Some thing wrong..').css('color','red');
                    }
                });//ajax ends here



    });//delete comment ends here
```

And here is my controller:

```
public function deletecomment()
    {
          $data['video_comment_id'] = $this->input->post('comment_id',TRUE);
         $deletecomment =  $this->mod_videosd->deletecomment($data);
         if ($deletecomment) 
         {
            echo 'yes';
         } 
         else
         {
            echo 'not';
         }

    }
```

And finally here is my database:

```
public function deletecomment($data)
{
    return $this->db->delete('video_comments',array('video_comment_id'=>$data['video_comment_id']));
}
```

Please help I am confused because I am not expert in jquery.

Comment: and its in my div here is code         <div class="media" data-id="<?php echo $row->video_comment_id ?>">

Answer (score 0):

Ok.. I think the problem is that you use the remove-function on the .data()-function. .data() returns just the value of an element, but not the element itself.(https://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/)
I didn't try it, but maybe $(this).remove() should work.
If you want to delete the whole div, you should give the div an id like . In the callbackfunction you have to to remove the div by $(#1337).remove(); (without .data())

Comment: i fixed it  $("div[data-id='" + theID + "']").remove();